# mobilefirst 7.1.0.00-20151005-1721 upgrade issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have upgraded the mobile first plugin using the Eclipse Marketplace today and ever since I did it whenever I deploy my app to the MFP server.

I am getting the below recurring/infinite warning in my console, which is driving me crazy.

I have tried it to see if there is problem in the app that installed but there is none in it.

> [WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /css/images/wl_app_warning.png

Can somebody help me resolve , i did not face such a problem before the upgrade

Thanks
-Raj

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Worklight error: File not found: /css/images/wl\_app\_warning.png](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095957/worklight-error-file-not-found-css-images-wl-app-warning-png)

Answer (score 0):

I have a project from a prior build in my workspace and I then upgraded to said newer build, and built my project. I did not get this warning.

If you can supply a project that shows this warning we can debug it.
Until then - can not confirm.