# Worklight error: File not found: /css/images/wl_app_warning.png

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have found an issue with my worklight project. What i have done here is as follows:

1. I have a project which was built and deployed without any issues.
2. I wanted to edit most of the images and re-arrange the whole images folder structure.
3. So I deleted all the contents in the images folder completely from eclipse so that i can save each new image to the newly created folders
4. Now, i created new folders in images folder and saved one image to one of the newly created folders.
5. I tried to run the application on mobileFirst development server and started getting the error message:

> "SRVE0190E: File not found: /css/images/wl_app_warning.png"

6. We did not even have a folder named images in css folder before.
   This is what happened for me and does this give any clue for the issue??
   Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project I created an "images" folder with an image:
[image]

I then used it in the HTML:

```
<img src="css/images/wl_app_warning.png"/>
```

No errors and the image is displayed...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Idan!! But the confusion here is that i do not need such an image and i do not know where in HTML i should include it even if i create one image as you mentioned.

Comment: There is no such image in a Worklight project.

Comment: Then i think some default images also got deleted when i deleted all the contents from images folder. Can you give me a screenshot of all the default images in images folder when we start a work-light project, so that i can replace those default images back to the images folder.

Comment: There are only two images, and none of them has that name: icon.png and thumbnail.png.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Idan!

Answer (score 1):

This is a defect in the admin service, and is tracked as APAR PI51055, which you can find more information about here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI51055

The issue has been corrected in iFix IF20151103-1015 and later builds.

If you have paid support, you will be able to download an iFix build from IBM Fix Central sometime soon that includes this fix - it is not out there for download right now, but I expect it will be within a couple of weeks.  If you need the fix before it appears on IBM Fix Central, you can open a PMR and ask the support team to provide it.  If you are using the free Developer Edition from the Eclipse Marketplace, I expect the fix will appear there soon also, and you can use the Eclipse software update function to get it, but I am not sure how frequently the Developer Edition repository is updated.

Comment: Thanks for this, @patbarron.  The link you provided seems to be dead.  I haven't been able to find anything about this issue by searching.  I did install 7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201511141616, but the problem persists.  Is there any work-around? Although everything seems to work, my log is so full of those messages it makes debugging real problems difficult!

Comment: I'm not sure why that link is dead - it shouldn't be...  I can't even find the APAR from the APAR search page right now, though I can view it from our internal systems.

Keep in mind, this is a server-side fix, so if you're seeing this on a production server, you need to upgrade the MFP Server (and do all the documented post-upgrade steps) as well as Studio.  I just looked, and can confirm this fix is in the 201511141616 build.

Comment: I will put a possible workaround in my next comment (it's too long to fit in this one).  Please excuse the formatting - I'm copy/pasting this from the APAR record, and I know that Stack Overflow is going to mess with the formatting....

Comment: "Assuming the build number is 201507070742, one possible workaroud for the customer could be to:1- extract the WAR file,2- edit the file worklight-management-ui/src/main/webapp/201507070742/js/applications/mfMainApplicationList.html3- Add the build number:<img ng-src="{{app.thumbnail}}" class="app-icon" alt="{{app.displayName}}" onerror="this.src='201507070742/css/images/wl_app_warning.png'"></img>4 - re-create the war file5 - uninstall the application from the application server/clear the cache and redeploy the updated WAR"

Comment: But, the workaround should not be necessary if you've applied the 201511141616 build (and performed all the post-upgrade steps) - this issue is definitely fixed in that build.

Comment: I pulled 7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201511141616 from an internal server and verified I have it applied to the server.  I have NOT updated Studio - didn't realize I would need that.  How do I get iFixes for Studio?

Comment: I would assume you'd be able to get the Studio fix from the same place you got the Server fix - the filename should look like "7.1.0.0-MFPF-StudioP2-IF201511141616.zip".  You'd add this archive file as an Eclipse software installation source, and update.  If you're having the problem in the embedded development server (within Studio) then you need to update Studio to get the fix.

Comment: Updating Studio as well as the server did the trick.  Thanks!