# mobilefirst 7.1.0.00-20151005-1721 upgrade issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

here is the follow up question to [mobilefirst 7.1.0.00-20151005-1721 upgrade issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093221/mobilefirst-7-1-0-00-20151005-1721-upgrade-issue) .

i have noticed that this issue is pertaining to eclipse luna and MFP 7-1-0-00-20151005-1721 combination and its not just me but all the members in my team who upgraded are facing the same problem no matter what app they want to use or deploy(even the newly created app). So i tried to install Mars and MFP 7-1-0-00-20151005 and i did not face that problem there, how ever i have observed that there are multiple deployments of admin, console,runtime, analytic war though it did not create any problem running the app on worklight console.

Thanks

Raj

Answer (score 0):

Note that the multiple .war files happens, but it harmless.

As for the problem with the image file, I installed the latest available 7.1 iFix (7.1.0.00-20151012-1525) in Eclipse Luna, created a new project -> application, built, and still no error.